# T-SQL: How to cast successfully a Null value to date type?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

In my example, I have a table with 1 column date and i insert 3 values 1 of them is null. As you can see in the first select the null value goes first after order by. In the 2 select, although i cast a string as date the previously null value after order by remains first . Here is my query you will understand better the problem if you run it! I have also tried convert

```
drop table table1

create table table1(
dates date)

insert into table1 values ('2017-9-1'),('2017-7-1'),(NULL)

select dates from table1 ORDER BY dates ASC

select ISNULL(dates,CAST('2020-04-25T15:50:59.997' AS date))from table1 ORDER BY dates ASC

select ISNULL(dates, '2017-8-1')from table1 ORDER BY dates ASC
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve - where did you expect / want the null value to appear ?

Comment: As you can see i do 'ORDER BY dates ASC ' So after cast I want the previous null value be ordered as the other values which is not happening.

Comment: so you need to order by the expression (dates is the field and still contains a null value) - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all your select statements you are ordering by date field - perhaps you wanted to order by the expression?

for example:

```
select dates from table1 ORDER BY dates ASC

select dates from table1 ORDER BY ISNULL(dates,CAST('2020-04-25T15:50:59.997' AS date)) ASC

select dates from table1 ORDER BY ISNULL(dates, '2017-8-1') ASC
```

or

```
select dates from table1 ORDER BY dates ASC

select ISNULL(dates,CAST('2020-04-25T15:50:59.997' AS date))from table1 
ORDER BY ISNULL(dates,CAST('2020-04-25T15:50:59.997' AS date)) ASC

select ISNULL(dates, '2017-8-1')from table1 
ORDER BY ISNULL(dates, '2017-8-1') ASC
```

or you can use a sub query

```
SELECT dates from ( 
  SELECT 
    ISNULL(dates,CAST('2020-04-25T15:50:59.997' AS date)) dates 
  FROM table1
) qry 
ORDER BY dates
```